# Why the compiler doesn't complain about overflowing a signed char?

Tags: c++, char, integer-overflow

I know it is bad idea and error-prone to assign an integer value to a signed char for example assigning the return value -which is int from `std::cin.peek()`, `std::cin.get(void)` to a `char`.

For example:

```
char c = 255; // Undefined Behavior. (overflowing a singed char)
```

And if I compile it using GCC with `pedantic` flags I'll get the warning:

`warning: overflow in conversion from ‘int’ to ‘char’ changes value from ‘255’ to ‘'\37777777777'’ [-Woverflow]|`.

It is OK and thanks to the compiler who warns about it.

But consider this:

```
char c;
if( (c = std::cin.peek()) == '\n')
    std::cout << "end of line char detected!\n";
```

Why the compiler doesn't complain about assigning the return value of `std::cin.get()` and `std::cin.peek()` into `c` which is of type `char`?

- I've compiled using the same compiler and the same flags.
- Does this mean because the value returned from a non-constexpr function is only known at runtime that is why the compiler doesn't compalin.
- I think it is correct my guess consider this:

  ```
    constexpr int f(){return 255;}

    int main(){

        char c = f();
    }
  ```
- Now because the function `f` is `constexpr` the compiler evaluates it at compile-time rather than at runtime so it knows that is overflowing a `char`, consequently it yields the warning.
- That is similar to the accessing elements of a container like `std::vector` when the index is known only at runtime, the compiler doesn't yields any warning because the value of the index is not there yet at compile-time.
- Are my guesses true?

Comment: `char c = 255; // Undefined Behavior. (overflowing a singed char)` Not necessarily. I've seen, but not worked on, computers with a 32 bit `char`. In fact, all of the integer types were 32 bit. Strange as it sounds, this is 100% legal. [All C++ requires of integer types is a minimum size and that it be no larger than the next larger type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Properties).

Comment: See if you get the error you expect with the `-Wconversion` flag. Edit: Tried it. I get the warning. https://godbolt.org/z/jahxv5qjE

Comment: The answer should be one of implicit conversion. The compiler can't know at compile time what value will be read at runtime, so it implicitly converts and keeps its mouth shut unless you ask for the extra diagnostic.

Comment: You can do that if you want.  `char to_char(int i) { if (i > 127 || i < -128) throw "oopsies"; return static_cast<char>(i); }`